# Is the source code and command history available for RSpec asciinema clips?

Tags: rspec

I'm working through the asciinema clips that shown how to setup a project with RSpec on [their homepage](http://rspec.info/).

Is the source and command history for their terminal recording example available anywhere? I'm having a hard time with pausing and restarting the videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is slow down the cast. Press `<` to slow down, and `>` to speed up. Use the left arrow to move back to the beginning. For more keyboard shortcuts, see https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema-player#keyboard-shortcuts

If you want to view the commands "raw," view the iFrame's source, and copy the URL to the JSON file it loads. Then load that JSON file.